# Flutter FCM does not show alerts on Android

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I get a notification in func `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message)` but on Android not showing alert, I'm using Realme RMX3370 Android 13. I asked for push notification permission when starting the app.

This is my code and config

[image: Code]
[image: Android Manifest]
[image: android/app/build.gradle]
[image: android/build.gradle]

Comment: are you using permission_handler to handle permission requests?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @Chalwe19 Yes, I'm using permission_handler